# VBA - When passing on 0,02 to an Integer, it's Value is 0

Tags: vba, excel, types, decimal

This function is used to determine a promotion-percentage based on the revenue of a customer. This is a example scaling:

```
Without Limit     -> 2.0%
from 30.000,-     -> 3,0%
from 50.000,-     -> 3,5%
from 75.000,-     -> 4,0%
```

All values are retrieved from an Excel sheet and stored in Longs.

The Problem is when the promotion tier is determined, I am passing the percentage value to the function (which is Datatype Integer).

```
PercentageInstallation = xSt3P
```

xSt3P is 0.03, but PercentageInstallation says 0.

Here is the function:

```
Public Function PercentageInstallation(xRwCtr As Integer, xKdnr1 As Integer, xSource As Worksheet) As Integer

    Dim xUmsatz, xOLiP, xSt1B, xSt1P, xSt2B, xSt2P, xSt3B, xSt3P, xSt4B, xSt4P As Long

    xUmsatz = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "I")    'Gesamtumsatz
    xOLiP = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "Q")      'ohne Limit
    xSt1B = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "R")      'Stufe 1 Betrag
    xSt1P = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "S")      'Stufe 1 Prozent
    xSt2B = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "T")      'Stufe 2 Betrag
    xSt2P = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "U")      'Stufe 2 Prozent
    xSt3B = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "V")      'Stufe 3 Betrag
    xSt3P = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "W")      'Stufe 3 Prozent
    xSt4B = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "X")      'Stufe 4 Betrag
    xSt4P = xSource.Cells(xRwCtr, "Y")      'Stufe 4 Prozent

    Debug.Print ("----------------------")
    Debug.Print ("> " & xUmsatz)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xOLiP)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt1B)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt1P)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt2B)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt2P)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt3B)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt3P)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt4B)
    Debug.Print ("> " & xSt4P)
    Debug.Print ("----------------------")


    If xUmsatz > xSt4B And xSt4B <> "" Then
        Debug.Print ("Its tier 4!")
        PercentageInstallation = xSt4P

    ElseIf xUmsatz > xSt3B And xSt3B <> "" Then
        Debug.Print ("Its tier 3!")
        PercentageInstallation = xSt3P

    ElseIf xUmsatz > xSt2B And xSt2B <> "" Then
        Debug.Print ("Its tier 2!")
        PercentageInstallation = xSt2P

    ElseIf xUmsatz > xSt1B And xSt1B <> "" Then
        Debug.Print ("Its tier 1!")
        PercentageInstallation = xSt1P

    ElseIf xOLiP <> "" Then
        Debug.Print ("Its tier without Limit!")
        PercentageInstallation = xOLiP

    Else
        Call Error(4, xKdnr1)

    End If

End Function
```

And here is the Output from Debug.Print:

```
----------------------
> 81475,57
> 0,02
> 30000
> 0,03
> 50000
> 0,035
> 75000
> 0,04
> 
> 0
----------------------
Its tier 3!
```

I tried to define the function as Long, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Use `Single` or `Double`. `Long` is just another integer type.

Comment: I should also mention that defining your variables like you do in the first line, only the last one is actually defined as a `Long`. The rest of them are defined as `Variant`.

Comment: FYI, your `Dim` statement is only declaring `xSt4P` as a Long, not the rest of them.  You need to specify the type for EACH variable, not just the one at the end.  You'll notice that your debug printing is rounding this variable and not the rest of them.  The answer correctly identifies the problem with the `Long` datatype, but I figured I'd mention this.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for pointing out my mistake about defining the variables. That saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on your Visual Basic for Applications data types [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx)

Code example for the basic numeric types:

```
Sub Some_sub()

Dim a As Double
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Single

a = 0.02 
b = 0.02 
c = 0.02 
d = 0.02 

Debug.Print a 'output: 0.02
Debug.Print b 'output: 0
Debug.Print c 'output: 0
Debug.Print d 'output: 0.02

End Sub
```

As said in the comments: Use Single or Double.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to understand the difference between different value types:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim k As Long
    Dim p As Double

    k = 0.4
    Debug.Print k

    k = 0.7
    Debug.Print k

    p = 0.4
    Debug.Print p

End Sub
```

The result would be in the immediate window.